# ngJsTree TypeError: scope.tree.jstree is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jstree, angular-module

I have included needed dependencies and the ngJsTree module to my app.module. But this still happens:

```
angular.js:13424 TypeError: scope.tree.jstree is not a function
at m.scope.destroy (ngJsTree.min.js:243)
at ngJsTree.min.js:286
at m.$digest (angular.js:16869)
at m.$apply (angular.js:17133)
at g (angular.js:11454)
at x (angular.js:11652)
at XMLHttpRequest.v.onload (angular.js:11593)
```

My includes:

```
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lodash.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect.js"></script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.0.9/jstree.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ngJsTree.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

My HTML:

```
<div js-tree="treeConfig" ng-model="googleDriveFiles" tree-events="ready:readyCB;changed:onItemChanged"></div>
```

Module part of app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
    'ngRoute','ngMaterial','angularjs-dropdown-multiselect','ngJsTree'
]);
```

Comment: Have you included jquery library js prior to these scripts?

Comment: Oh yes. jQuery is included on top of the index.html

Comment: The issue was because there was one angular.min.js before jquery in the head tag.

Comment: So you learned one thing 

Comment: @ABUdhay yeah. Thanks!!

Comment: could you solve the problem!?
I'm still in touch

Comment: @MohammadJavadSeyyedi "The issue was because there was one angular.min.js before jquery in the head tag." Check your HTML file carefully for script tags, and make sure you have included all the needed libraries.